# How to select all check boxes with same element id using Selenium with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver

I am new to using Selenium and I have only a very rudimentary knowledge about HTML so please bear with me. I am trying to automate exporting a list of contacts from our company website to be used in an Access database. The list is in a table with multiple pages that can display up to 1000 records at a time, each with its own check box used to select the record for export. In the past, I have been able to click the "Select All" option and export everything all at once, but the way my company has set it up, I am limited to export 10000 records (of about 90K) at a time. I thought it would be easy to just go in and click each check box by their unique id or name, but they all have the same id `selectedResps-1` and name `selectedResps` and 2 alternating xpaths (alternating colors in the table):

`/html/body[@class='appbody']/table[@id='tileLayoutTbl']/tbody/tr[3]/td/form[@id='respSearchForm']/div[@id='srmGlobal']/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[@id='results']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[@id='scrollingDiv']/table[@id='respSearchList']/tbody/tr[@class='oddrow']`

or

`/html/body[@class='appbody']/table[@id='tileLayoutTbl']/tbody/tr[3]/td/form[@id='respSearchForm']/div[@id='srmGlobal']/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[@id='results']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[@id='scrollingDiv']/table[@id='respSearchList']/tbody/tr[@class='rowGrey']`.

I am hoping that there is something that I can do like what's below to select them all:

```
 For Each CheckBox in Table
      If CheckBox.Name = "selectedResps" then
          'Check the checkbox
      End If
 Next CheckBox
```

This would let me export 1000 contacts at a time which would let me get around the 10000 record per export limitation.

Update -

Following @JeffC's advice, I found that the .FindElements() function returns a WebElements collection and have come up with some code that I thought should work:

```
Dim PageCollection As WebElements
Dim Item As WebElement
Dim D As New IEDriver

Set PageCollection = D.FindElementsByCssSelector("#SelectedReps-1")

For Each Item In PageCollection
    Item.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Next Item
```

The issue that I am running into is that `PageCollection` is empty (found with the `.Count` property) so the for loop doesn't do anything. I have validated that it will work by using one of the Xpaths from above in `.FindElementsByXpath()`, I just need to know why `PageCollection` won't populate. Do I need to point Selenium towards a certain part of the page to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a typo for the name. The code below works perfectly, albeit a little slow:

```
Dim D As New IEDriver
Dim PageCollection As WebElements
Dim Item As WebElement

Set PageCollection = D.FindElementById("respSearchList").FindElementsById("selectedResps-1")

For Each Item In PageCollection
    Item.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Next Item
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do Selenium VBA but I can tell you how it can be done with Java and hopefully you can translate the concepts...

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#selectedResps-1"));
for (WebElement checkbox : checkboxes)
{
    checkbox.click();
}
```

So basically you want to pull all elements with the id (#) "selectedResps-1". In Java that returns a List<>, I don't know what it returns in VBA. Whatever it returns, you want to loop through that collection type with a `for` or `for each`, etc. and click on each element.

With the page as large as you say it is, you may have to add a slight delay between clicks because the page may need a moment between clicks to process the click.

Is there not a way to limit the search results on the page and then use the Select All box?

Comment: I will do some research if there is anything similar to the List<> function in VBA, hopefully there is something that works. 

As for limiting the page results, unfortunately the website was poorly designed so the select all will always select all available records and not just the ones on the current page.

Comment: Just find out what `.findElements()` returns... that should be some sort of collection, then iterate through it.